# Simple regular expression(Pattern) for a decimal with a precision of 2

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have number input text box.It has 2 digit precision value. My requirement is that it should accept only 15 digit number along with precision.I have tried with several regular expression but haven't worked. Could you please suggest regular expression or pattern for it.

Comment: show the exemplary input and the expected output to get a quick answer

Comment: Which language are you using? Regex is not standardized, you know.

Comment: @sweeper-normal regular expression which accpets 15 digit along with 2 digit precision

Comment: Maybe `^\d{1,15}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:
`\d{1,15}`

Comment: does it allow precision (2 digit)?